# In compiled Scala, what is the bitmap$0 field?

Tags: scala

I have noticed some of my Scala classes contain a field with the name `bitmap$0` of type `int`. What is this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's where the initialization states for `lazy val`s are stored.  When you access a `lazy val` (or a nested `object`, which is equivalent), the compiler uses the bitmap field to determine whether it's already been evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

When lazy vals are initialized, this field is also used for synchronization when the value is initialized.