# Gson in Scala: extra field `bitmap$0` in serialized Json output

Tags: scala, gson

I use Gson in Scala to serialize a simple Scala class:

```
case class Statistics(source: String,
                      count: Integer,
                      sum: Double,
                      average: Double,
                      median: Double,
                      maximum: Double,
                      minimum: Double) {
  def toJson: JsonElement = Config.GSON.toJsonTree(this)
  [...]
}
```

`GSON` is defined in a separate object `Config`:

```
lazy val GSON: Gson = new GsonBuilder()
.setPrettyPrinting()
.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
.disableHtmlEscaping()
.create()
```

The output of `toJson` looks as expected:

```
{
"Source": "test",
"Count": 45,
"Sum": 38.73403662,
"Average": 0.8607563693333333,
"Median": 0.60809594,
"Maximum": 2.5913415,
"Minimum": 0.418911,
},
```

Now I wanted to add some logging the the `Statistics` class, using `LazyLogging`:

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging

case class Statistics(source: String,
                      count: Integer,
                      sum: Double,
                      average: Double,
                      median: Double,
                      maximum: Double,
                      minimum: Double) extends LazyLogging {
  def toJson: JsonElement = Config.GSON.toJsonTree(this)
  [...]
}
```

Now the output of `toJson` gets an additional field `Bitmap$0`.

```
{
"Source": "test",
"Count": 45,
"Sum": 38.73403662,
"Average": 0.8607563693333333,
"Median": 0.60809594,
"Maximum": 2.5913415,
"Minimum": 0.418911,
"Bitmap$0": false
},
```

I have tried to exclude add an exclusion strategy for a specific class by adapting [this recipe from the Gson docs](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html):

```
class SpecificClassExclusionStrategy(excludedThisClass: Class[_]) extends ExclusionStrategy {

  import com.google.gson.FieldAttributes

  def shouldSkipClass(clazz: Class[_]): Boolean = excludedThisClass == clazz

  def shouldSkipField(f: FieldAttributes): Boolean = excludedThisClass == f.getDeclaredClass
}
```

And added it to the `GSON` object:

```
lazy val GSON: Gson = new GsonBuilder()
.setPrettyPrinting()
.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
.disableHtmlEscaping()
.addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new SpecificClassExclusionStrategy(classOf[LazyLogging]))
.create()
```

This does not make a difference though.
My 1st question is thus: where does the obscure `Bitmap$0` field come from in the first place.
The 2nd is: how can I prevent Gson from serializing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exclusion strategy is not meant to filter superclasses; it acts on fields and objects (values of fields).

You should use something along the following:

```
class SpecificFieldExclusionStrategy() extends ExclusionStrategy {

  import com.google.gson.FieldAttributes

  def shouldSkipClass(clazz: Class[_]): Boolean = false

  def shouldSkipField(f: FieldAttributes): Boolean = f.getName == "bitmap$0"
}
```

Regarding bitmap$0, it is answered in another question: [In compiled Scala, what is the bitmap$0 field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877040/in-compiled-scala-what-is-the-bitmap0-field)

Comment: Thanks, the following actually works: `def shouldSkipField(f: FieldAttributes): Boolean = f.getName == "bitmap$0"`. However, that does not explain where the `bitmap$0` field comes from.

Comment: I've edited the answer according to your observations.